# Android, Linux and iOS - using of Bluetooth and TCP/IP?

Tags: android, ios, tcp, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Since many libraries are meant to be used with TCP/IP, I was wondering if it is possible to activate TCP/IP and therefore TCP/UDP for Bluetooth connections. I found some information already like that it is called Bluetooth PAN and piconet.

Furthermore, I noticed that my Android device created a network interface with an IP upon a connection with an iPhone (after I paired it and hit connect). Nevertheless, it appears that interface cannot be used right away. I don't have the option to root these devices so it needs to be activated programmatically somehow.

Any hints? Is it actually possible?
Thanks.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android11-platform-release/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.java  ... if I understand it correctly, Bluetooth PAN cannot be used on Android at the moment and its up to the system to allow it ?

Comment: side note: enabling tcp/ip via bluetooth settings & its tethering permits the usage of tcp/ip over bluetooth but there are no APIs to do so :-(